# PATH, resolve location of exe

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, git, powershell

Consider the following PATH

`c:\App1\;c:\App2\`

App1 directory contains the application Foo.exe 
App2 directory contains the application Bar.exe

Now when I'm in a CMD window I can type either Foo.exe or Bar.exe.

Now is there a way to know, when I type Foo.exe, that it resolves to C:\App1\Foo.exe.

I need to know because I have one application that intervenes with the `start .` command, which I use extensively in Powershell (when working with a Git repository).

Comment: If I remember, `start` checks first the working directory then the %PATH% variables by order. So yes it should resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `where` command.

```
C:\Users\gronostaj>where grep
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\grep.exe
C:\FPC\2.6.0\bin\i386-Win32\grep.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\grep.exe
```

First one is executed when you type its name.

And remember that current working directory always has priority over PATH in Windows.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>where grep
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\grep.exe
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\grep.exe
C:\FPC\2.6.0\bin\i386-Win32\grep.exe
```

Comment: Okay, that indeed works. However, where does the `start` command comes from? Because `where start` yields `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: `start` isn't a program, but a built-in command of cmd/Powershell (so are `copy`, `del` etc.). But the point is, if you want to for example `start notepad`, then `where notepad` will tell you which `notepad` it will be.

Comment: Note that `where.exe` returns all the paths where it finds the executable, while the interpreter will use only the first one. You should reckon with that or use `which.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `PATH` is the environment variable, use `$exeLocation = Get-Command $exename | Select -Expand Path`